# how to protect against Null Byte Injection in a java webapp

Tags: java, security, web-applications, xss

How can null byte injection be done on a java webapp, Or rather - how does on protect against it?

Should I look at each byte of the request parameter and inspect its 'byte' value to be 0 ? I can't imagine a 0 byte sneaking in a request parameter... can it?

My main aim is to make sure the filename used for saving the file is safe enough. And for now, I am not looking answers that recommend (for example): replacing ALL non-word characters with Underscore.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/378/is-null-byte-injection-possible-in-java-filenames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing the user to store files with arbitrary names is dangerous. What happens if the user provides `"../../../WINDOWS/explorer.exe"`? You should restrict filenames to only contain characters known to be harmless.

`'\0'` is not known to be harmless. As far as Java is concerned, `'\0'` is a character like any other. However, the operating system is likely to interpret `'\0'` as the end of a string. If a string is passed from Java to the operating system, that different interpretation could result in exploitable bugs. Consider:

```
if (filename.endsWith(".txt") {
    store(filename, data);
}
```

where filename is "C:\Windows\explorer.exe\0.txt", which ends with ".txt" to Java, but with ".exe" to the operating system.

Comment: This was used to upload `.jsp\0.html` files to jroller, with the result of code execution on the server.

Comment: @meriton how would one inspect the filename ? Should we loop over the bytes[] of the string and look for 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're concerned with null byte injection.  Java isn't like C/C++, where strings are null-terminated character arrays.

You ought to bind and validate parameters and values coming in from the web tier.  How do you define "safe enough"?

Comment: But is Java sucseptible to a `null bute injection` or not?Input validation should be done I agree, but the OP has a specific concern.Anyway it seems that it is somehow possible.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  If it's a file path, and I "inject" a null byte into the middle of it, what happens?  Sounds like an invalid path to me.

Comment: Java Null Byte Injection is surprisingly overlooked by community. There are solid reasons for that: after all, Java does not use null byte as the End Of String symbol.

However, Java IO libraries hand off strings to the underlying OS, which in most cases uses ‘C’ engine for final processing.  And the ‘C’ processor always rejects anything beyond the null byte character.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1 **Scan the string (convert it to a char array first) for null bytes.**

2 upgrade to Java 8 or Java 7u40 and you are protected. (Yes, i tested it!, it works!)

in May 1013 Oracle fixed the problem: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846

Answer (score 0):

Null byte injection in filenames was fixed in Java 7 update 40 (released around Sept. 2013). So, its been fixed for a while now, but it WAS a problem for over a decade and it was a NASTY vulnerability in Java. The fix is documented here: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846

-Dave Wichers