# Null Byte Injection check in Java app or What is a Null Byte

Tags: java, security, xss

How does one protect against Null Byte injection?
see: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/378

If a request parameter is going to used as a filename, should we look at each byte of the request parameter and inspect its 'byte' value to be 0 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to protect against Null Byte Injection in a java webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182261/how-to-protect-against-null-byte-injection-in-a-java-webapp)

Comment: To make the answer to that question clearer: **Never trust the Client**. Yes, you should be validating user input, including filenames. A regex would solve this for you.

Comment: It appears that you're correct.  You have to check the value of each byte, and reject any input that contains X'00'.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  what is X'00'

Comment: probably, GilbertLeBlanc meant Null bite itself - which is just a "zero".

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices:

1 **Scan the Java string (convert it to a char array first) for null bytes.**

2 Sanitize user input (i.e. check for '%00' - it is a URL-encoded null byte.). But beware! Hackers use different encodings, so #1 is safer!

3 upgrade to Java 8 or Java 7u40 and you are protected. (Yes, i tested it!, it works!)

in May 1013 Oracle fixed the problem: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846